# Install OpenType fonts in Texlive

Tags: opentype

Maybe this topic has already been discussed, but I haven't found anything clear about it! I bought Garamond Opentype fonts by Adobe, so I have *.otf font files. I'd like to use it in my thesis, but i can't install it in TexLive 2011! I've downloaded pad.zip file from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/w-a-schmidt, and after long hours I sucessfully converted .otf to .pfb. Then I used Crossfont to obtain the .afm file... and now? Do I need any other file? I read that using autoinst may help, but how?
Please, help!

Comment: Are you willing and able to use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead of (pdf)LaTeX? If so, you could use either of these programs to good effect since they can load and use `.otf` fonts directly, without any need to create pfb, afm, and other files.

Answer (score 4):

The package by Walter Schmidt is meant for the Type 1 fonts.

For the use with (pdf)latex, try the [fonttools](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/utilities/fontools/) with autoinst. This script generates all necessary files including a LaTeX package. It is well documented. However, you won't have math support.

As Mico suggested, you can use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with the fontspec package to use the otf directly.

Comment: I've seen that FontPro started with rudimentary support for Adobe Garamond, can I hope for further development?

Comment: @mafp The Garamond files were written by the original MinionPro project team. My time is very limited at the moment and I am also not that much interested. The actual adaptation using MnSymbol shouldn't be hard so I could give some starting hints.

Comment: That would be great.

Comment: @mafp Let's do it via PM. Please write me an email. Please let me know whether you understand German so I could copy/paste what I've written before.