# How do I use freeserif font in latex

Tags: fonts, fontspec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install OpenType fonts in Texlive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62288/install-opentype-fonts-in-texlive)

I am looking to create some documents in LibreOffice and LaTeX. To maintain consistency I want to use the same font `FreeSerif` in both set of documents. Is there a way to use `FreeSerif` fonts in LaTeX?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62288/16895

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}
```

And run xelatex.

Comment: Ought to mention that `fontspec` is Xe/LuaTeX only - not for pdfTeX users...