# Bi-coloured EB Garamond initials using the ebgaramond package

Tags: ebgaramond

I am very fascinated by https://tex-talk.net/2011/08/putting-colors-in-initials/
[image]
and I have noticed that EB Garamond now has its own LaTeX package [`ebgaramond`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ebgaramond?lang=en) but when I am trying to look into i, I don't see how I can reproduce these coloured initials using it. Am I right in thinking that the `ebgaramond` package does not come with the initial font separated into background and letters? Or am I missing something?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277331 (but first get Georg Duffner’s fonts, not the revision by Octavio Pardo found in TeX Live).

Comment: Hm I did want the D though. Seems the font in the package has the D but not the font I downloaded from https://bitbucket.org/georgd/eb-garamond/downloads/ :(

Comment: There’s now a separate repository for the initials: https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond-Initials